# Is there a way to export ALL translations into a single .PO file?

Tags: i18n-l10n

To translate my website, I need to export translations one by one per group type.

This gets to be confusing as some fields share core terms ect...

Is there a way to do a consolidated ONE .po file for all translations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each entry in .po file has only two strings;

```
msgid untranslated-string
msgstr translated-string
```

Thus, by it's very nature it can only keep two languages: original and one translation. So no, there is no way to do it because format does not support that. For details, see [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html).